# Extract table from CSV in Python with BS

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a huge HTML file which contains many tables and I want to save it as CSV file.

I have a code to export all tables from an html file but when I run it, nothing happens! Is there anyway to troubleshoot this? I am using BS and panda.

It just opens the file and looks for the table.

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

path = 'index.html'

soup = bs(open(path),'html.parser')

def get_all_tables(soup):
    """Extracts and returns all tables in a soup object"""
    return soup.find_all("table")


def get_table_headers(table):
    """Given a table soup, returns all the headers"""
    headers = []
    for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th"):
        headers.append(th.text.strip())
    return headers


def get_table_rows(table):
    """Given a table, returns all its rows"""
    rows = []
    for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
        cells = []
        # grab all td tags in this table row
        tds = tr.find_all("td")
        if len(tds) == 0:
            # if no td tags, search for th tags
            # can be found especially in wikipedia tables below the table
            ths = tr.find_all("th")
            for th in ths:
                cells.append(th.text.strip())
        else:
            # use regular td tags
            for td in tds:
                cells.append(td.text.strip())
        rows.append(cells)
    return rows


def save_as_csv(table_name, headers, rows):
    pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers).to_csv(f"{table_name}.csv")


def main(path):
    # get the soup
    soup = get_soup(path)
    # extract all the tables from the file
    tables = get_all_tables(soup)
    print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(tables)} tables.")
    # iterate over all tables
    for i, table in enumerate(tables, start=1):
        # get the table headers
        headers = get_table_headers(table)
        # get all the rows of the table
        rows = get_table_rows(table)
        # save table as csv file
        table_name = f"table-{i}"
        print(f"[+] Saving {table_name}")
        save_as_csv(table_name, headers, rows)
```

Comment: Does it tell you that it found tables?  You have defined `main`, but are you actually calling `main()`?

Comment: As @TimRoberts said, just add main(path) at the end of your script. This will execute all the code above